# Split a string in Java containing (

Tags: java, string, split

I am trying to split a string in Java.

For example

```
Hello (1234)
```

The part after ( must not be included in the string.
I am expecting the following:

```
Hello
```

How would you do it?

Comment: Split by empty spaces maybe?

Comment: there is a method called split in string class.

Comment: Will it always follow this pattern?

Comment: .split(\\() does not work.

Comment: `"Hello (1234)".split("\\s*\\(");`

Comment: The string is random, sometimes it contains the Hello (1234) and sometimes it just has Hello.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just split according to

- zero or more spaces.
- And the following `(` character.
- Then get the value from   index 0 of splitted parts.

  ```
  "Hello (1234)".split("\\s*\\(")[0];
  ```

or

```
    "Hello (1234)".split("\\s+")[0];
```

Comment: If you're going to use `[0]` you can simply split by `"\\s*"`

Comment: Yes. Since OP doesn't need the ext after the empty spaces, you can just use `"Hello (<whatever>)".split("\\s*")[0]` and the parenthesis is irrelevant.

Comment: you mean `\\s+` ? `\\s*` will do split after each char.

Comment: think he want to split on `(` and also the leading spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the contents in the parenthesis by nothing.

```
    String str = "Hello(1234)";
    String result = str.replaceAll("\\(.*\\)", "");
    System.out.println(result);
```

You mention split operation in the question, but you say

> The part after ( must not be included in the string. I am expecting
>   the following:

So I'm assuming you are discarding the `(1234)` ? If you need to save it, consider the other answer (using `split`)

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following regex

```
  String[] split = "Hello (1234)".split("\\s*\\([\\d]*\\)*");
  System.out.println(split[0]);
```

\\s* space may be ignored
\\( ( or left parenthesis has special meaning in regex so \\( means only ( 
            Same is the case with ) or right parenthesis \\) 
\\d* digits may be present

 You may use + instead of * if that character is present at-least once